How to recreate Bob and Alice Non-Interactive Diffie-Hellman Key-Exchange?
I'm trying to recreate the Bob and Alice Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, since I'm doing my first steps in cryptography and cyber security.
The goal is to implement a non-interactive version of this protocol, where Alice has access to Bob's public key, and carries out a "key agreement" to establish a session key that is used in an authenticated cipher of a file. In detail, Alice must:

Access Bob's public key (pkBob);
Use the public parameters of this key to generate a DH key pair (skAlice, pkAlice);
Use pkBob and her own private key to derive a session key K;
Encrypt the intended message using an authenticated cipher;
Record the file "cryptogram" containing:
5.a. Public key pkAlice
5.b. Cryptogram of the authenticated cipher

To decrypt the message, Bob must:

Derive the session key K from his private key (skBob) and pkAlice;
Decrypt the cryptogram of the authenticated cipher using K.

To get this done, I currently have the following code:
const crypto = require("crypto")
const fs = require("fs")

function serializeKey(key) {
  return key.toString("base64")
}


function deserializeKey(pem, type) {
  return Buffer.from(pem, "base64")
}


function generateDHKeys(user) {
  const dh = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048)
  const privateKey = dh.generateKeys()
  const publicKey = dh.getPublicKey()

  const publicKeyPEM = serializeKey(publicKey)
  const privateKeyPEM = serializeKey(privateKey)

  fs.writeFileSync(`${user}.pk`, publicKeyPEM, "utf8")
  fs.writeFileSync(`${user}.sk`, privateKeyPEM, "utf8")
}


function getSharedSecret(myPrivateKeyPEM, theirPublicKeyPEM) {
  const dh = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048)
  dh.setPrivateKey(deserializeKey(myPrivateKeyPEM))
  const theirPublicKey = deserializeKey(theirPublicKeyPEM)
  const secret = dh.computeSecret(theirPublicKey)
  return secret
}


function encryptWithAESGCM(secret, message) {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12) // AES-GCM recommends 12-byte IVs
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", secret.slice(0, 32), iv)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(message, "utf8", "hex")
  encrypted += cipher.final("hex")
  const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString("hex")
  return { encrypted, iv: iv.toString("hex"), authTag }
}


function decryptWithAESGCM(secret, encryptedData) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-gcm", secret.slice(0, 32), Buffer.from(encryptedData.iv, "hex"))
  decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(encryptedData.authTag, "hex"))
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedData.encrypted, "hex", "utf8")
  decrypted += decipher.final("utf8")
  return decrypted
}


function encryptMessage(user, filePath) {
  const myPrivateKeyPEM = fs.readFileSync(`${user}.sk`, "utf8")
  const theirPublicKeyPEM = fs.readFileSync(`${user}.pk`, "utf8")

  const secret = getSharedSecret(myPrivateKeyPEM, theirPublicKeyPEM)

  const message = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8")
  const { encrypted, iv, authTag } = encryptWithAESGCM(secret, message)

  const outputFilePath = `${filePath}.enc`
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify({ encrypted, iv, authTag }))
}

function decryptMessage(user, encryptedFilePath) {
  const myPrivateKeyPEM = fs.readFileSync(`${user}.sk`, "utf8")
  const theirPublicKeyPEM = fs.readFileSync(`${user}.pk`, "utf8")

  const secret = getSharedSecret(myPrivateKeyPEM, theirPublicKeyPEM)

  const encryptedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(encryptedFilePath, "utf8"))
  const decryptedMessage = decryptWithAESGCM(secret, encryptedData)

  const outputFilePath = `${encryptedFilePath}.dec`
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, decryptedMessage, "utf8")
}

function main() {
  const args = process.argv.slice(2)
  const operation = args[0]

  switch (operation) {
    case "set":
      generateDHKeys(args[1])
      break
    case "enc":
      encryptMessage(args[1], args[2])
      break
    case "dec":
      decryptMessage(args[1], args[2])
      break
    default:
      console.log("Unknown Operation:", operation)
  }
}

main()

node diffie.js set bob -> Creates Bob's keys
node diffie.js set alice -> Creates Alice's keys
node diffie.js enc bob test_file -> Encrypts test_file
node diffie.js dec bob test_file.enc -> Decrypts test_file.enc

I'm able to successfully generate both Bob's and Alice's keys and to encrypt the test_file which has a simple message, but whenever I try to decrypt it, it gives me errors that tend me to believe that I'm not handling the encryption properly. I'm using AES-GCM but I could be using any other algorithm, the goal is to be able to use Diffie-Hellman successfully, not the cipher algorithm used per se.
How could I handle this differently?

Are the shared secrets the same for encryption and decryption? Does decryptWithAESGCM() work if the same value is used for secret as for encryptWithAESGCM()?

No, apparently they're different. I'm also getting the following error when calling the decryption functions:
node:internal/crypto/cipher:193
const ret = this[kHandle].final();
^
Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data

@Topaco I've changed the code, I'm now able to get the same secret. After running the Decryption, it is now working properly! Thank you!!!
The problem was with the lack of params p and g, where p is the large prime and g is the generator.

BTW, PEM format is NOT simply encoding the key in base64; see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2 . While just using base64 is often a useful approach, it should not be called PEM. (Conversely PEM should not be called base64, as MSWindows certificate-export dialog does.)
